# Xslt - how to group by and show output in same row in XSLT only partial output is showing with current code

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Can you pls help me with this code resolution

My scenario is to display results based on Location I need to output two fields for each location. I am using grouping to achieve this. The Hours fields is same for all the locations and payrate combination but the Employee count field is different. That is causing the issue.

my XML code:

```
<wd:Report_Data
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/TEST_PB">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:location>Canada</wd:location>
        <wd:payRate>Salary</wd:payRate>
        <wd:salcount>10</wd:salcount>
        <wd:hours>250</wd:hours>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:location>Canada</wd:location>
        <wd:payRate>Hourly</wd:payRate>
        <wd:hrlycount>3</wd:hrlycount>
        <wd:hours>120</wd:hours>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:location>Canada</wd:location>
        <wd:payRate>CWR</wd:payRate>
        <wd:cwrcount>2</wd:cwrcount>
        <wd:hours>100</wd:hours>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:location>USA</wd:location>
        <wd:payRate>Salary</wd:payRate>
        <wd:salcount>7</wd:salcount>
        <wd:hours>200</wd:hours>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:location>USA</wd:location>
        <wd:payRate>Hourly</wd:payRate>
        <wd:hrlycount>5</wd:hrlycount>
        <wd:hours>500</wd:hours>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:location>USA</wd:location>
        <wd:payRate>CWR</wd:payRate>
        <wd:cwrcount>10</wd:cwrcount>
        <wd:hours>700</wd:hours>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/TEST_PB" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">

 <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="NEWLINE" select="'&#xa;'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="COMMA" select="','"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:call-template name="DetailRecords"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
   <xsl:template name="DetailRecords">
        
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:location">
         <xsl:sort select="wd:location"/>       

                <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:location,$COMMA)"/>
                <xsl:if test="wd:payRate = 'Salary'">
                               <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/wd:hours" separator="," />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="wd:payRate = 'Hourly'">
                               <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/wd:hours" separator="," />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="wd:payRate = 'CWR'">
                               <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/wd:hours" separator="," />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="wd:payRate = 'Salary'">
                               <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/wd:salcount" separator="," />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="wd:payRate = 'Hourly'">
                               <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/wd:hrlycount" separator="," />     
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="wd:payRate = 'CWR'">
                               <xsl:value-of select=" wd:cwrcount" separator="," />                            
                </xsl:if>   
               <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>    
             </xsl:for-each-group>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
***Current Output:***
Canada,250,120,10010
USA,200,500,7007

***Expected Output:***
Canada,250,10,120,3,100,2
USA,200,7,500,5,700,10
```

Comment: it appears that those ifs are messing with your result. General, you should have one if per one result. So, if it is cwr, you should have one if and put both values inside it. But I don't know enought to give proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want e.g. (XSLT 3)

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:location">
     <xsl:sort select="wd:location"/>       
     <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), current-group()!(wd:hours, wd:salcount, wd:hrlycount, wd:cwrcount)" separator=","/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>    
  </xsl:for-each-group>
```

or (XSLT 2)

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:location">
     <xsl:sort select="wd:location"/>       
     <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), for $e in current-group() return ($e/wd:hours, $e/wd:salcount, $e/wd:hrlycount, $e/wd:cwrcount)" separator=","/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>    
  </xsl:for-each-group>
```

I am not sure why the question is tagged as xslt-1.0 if it uses `xsl:for-each-group` introduced in XSLT 2.0

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, I appreciate your answer. The output shows  first count then hours. It should be First hours then counts is there any tweak you can suggest please.
Canada,9,250,3,120,2,100
USA,7,200,5,500,10,700

Comment: If the order is wrong then the XSLT 3 suggestion with `!` should help. Which XSLT processor do you use? XSLT 3 is supported in Saxon 9.8 and later, SaxonJS 2, AltovaXML 2017 R3 and later. I will need to think about ensuring the order in XSLT 2.

Comment: see the edit of the XSLT 2 using `for .. return`

Comment: You are awesome Martin, XSLT 3 worked. I will check xslt 2 as well.